# Ошибка: порядковый номер 322 не найден в библиотеке dll libeay32.dll

Tags: php, xampp

Пробовал гуглить, но [корпорация добра](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20322%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%20dll%20libeay32.dll&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20322%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%20dll%20libeay32.dll&aqs=chrome..69i57.303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) на этот раз бессильна. Ошибка вылазит при попытке запуска xampp'a. [Самый популярный ответ](http://pvision.ru/forum?a=showtopic&topicid=2311&postid=15847#15847_)

> Попробуйте удалить файл "LIBEAY32.dll" из каталога с программой. В папке "windows\system32\" есть точно такой же, различия лишь в версиях. Возможно они и не дружат...

привёл лишь к ошибке

> Порядковый номер 4xxx не найден в библиотеке dll libeay32.dll

Пробовал переустанавливать - не помогло. Версия windows x64, если чем-то поможет 
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться в чём дело.

Comment: google://LIBEAY32.dll xampp  находит уйму ссылок (это я про корпорацию добра), гуглить ошибки на русском - время тратить

Comment: windows x64 - этоне версия, а платформа

Answer (score -1):

найди все экземпляры файла libeay32.dll, выбери самый свежий, положи его в C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Остальные удали или переименуй в 000libeay32.dll